# Can Omnipay be used if you don't own the server?

Tags: omnipay

Omnipay uses something called "GetComposer.com" for installation whos purpose is apparently to download and install other, required software.

Am I correct that this means Omnipay cannot be used in a shared hosting environment where you don't have hands-on-metal access to the hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's unanswered so....No, you're not correct.

Composer simply downloads the required libraries for your application.  It does require terminal access (Putty for example) to the machine, and that's about the only limitation you could see on a shared hosting environment.  Some allow it, others do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Omnipay on your website installed on external hosting. To do this first you need to download all libraries on local machine with use Composer an application-level dependency manager. But You must have installed web server with PHP on You local machine.(for example XAMPP) You need to use Command Prompt on Windows or Terminal on Linux to download libraries with use Composer. Then just copy "Vendor" folder to your hosting through FTP. Remember to use proper version of PHP.